# How can I replace a image in a word document using Novacode Docx

Tags: replace, photo, docx

I want to  replace a image in a word document using Novacode Docx but i just know insert by this code

```
var gDoc = DocX.Load(@"MauPhieuNhapCBCC.docx");
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            System.Drawing.Image myImg = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"img.jpg");

            myImg.Save(ms, myImg.RawFormat);  // Save your picture in a memory stream.
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            Image img = gDoc.AddImage(ms); // Create image.
            Picture pic1 = img.CreatePicture(); 
            // Create picture.
            var abc = gDoc.Paragraphs.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Pictures.Count > 0);
            abc.Alignment = Alignment.right;
            abc.InsertPicture(pic1,29).Position(0.3); // Insert picture into paragraph.
        }
        gDoc.SaveAs("Exported.docx");
```

How can I cant replace or insert in a special position?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this, it might not be the ideal way but it works properly:

```
var gDoc = DocX.Load(@"MauPhieuNhapCBCC.docx");
for (int f = 0; f < gDoc.Images.Count; f++) //Loop through the images of the document
            {
                Novacode.Image imo = gDoc.Images[f]; //Get image of the docuemnt
                if (imo.Id == "imageIdInDocument") //Check the id
                {
                    using (SD.Image newImg = SD.Image.FromFile("newImagePath")) //Load the new image for replacement
                    {
                        SD.Bitmap bMa = new SD.Bitmap(imo.GetStream(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite));
                        SD.Graphics graf = SD.Graphics.FromImage(bMa);
                        graf.Clear(SD.Color.White); //Set the image of the document all white

                        //Below we insert our new image over the one in the document
                        //We might need to change the image size to fit the area of our existing image
                        //If that were the case we give a function to resize images
                        SD.Image newResizeImg = meths.ResizeImage(newImg, newWidth, newHeight);

                        //Below we set the point(0, 0) to overlap the new image from the top left corner
                        graf.DrawImage(newResizeImg, new SD.Rectangle(new SD.Point(0, 0), newResizeImg.Size),
                        new SD.Rectangle(new SD.Point(), newResizeImg.Size), SD.GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                        bMa.Save(imo.GetStream(FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write), SD.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    }

                }
            }
```

Here the function to resize images:

```
public SD.Image ResizeImage(SD.Image img, int newWidth, int newHeight)
    {
        if (img.Width < newWidth && img.Height < newHeight) return img;
        using (img)
        {
            SD.Bitmap cpy = new SD.Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight, SD.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            using (SD.Graphics gr = SD.Graphics.FromImage(cpy))
            {
                gr.Clear(SD.Color.Transparent);
                gr.InterpolationMode = SD.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                gr.DrawImage(img, new SD.Rectangle(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight), new SD.Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height), SD.GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            }
            return cpy;
        }
    }
```

What we basically did was to get the image of the document, paint it white and set the new image inside the existent one with the same size or smaller.
Hope this helps someone.